# Concatenate Two Python Bunches Of Same Structure

Tags: python, merge, scikit-learn

What is the proper way to concatenate two bunches of exactly same structure in Python?

(originally I have asked about merge, but "merge" is hard to define)

Sklearn is using two Bunch objects to separately store the train and test data. I need to concatenate them. As a result I would like to have a new bunch containing all the data from test and train bunches. Duplicated entries are fine.

Here is an example structure of the bunches. But I suppose there should be a generic method independent of the bunch content as far as both bunches have exactly same structure.

```
Key             Type        Size
DESCR           NoneType    1
data            list        2
target_names    list        6212
filenames       int32       (6212L,)
target          string744   (6212L,)
```

here is an excerpt from the documentation for the [function that actually](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/datasets/base.py#L94) creates those bunches:

```
def load_files(container_path, description=None, categories=None,
           load_content=True, shuffle=True, encoding=None,
           decode_error='strict', random_state=0):
"""Load text files with categories as subfolder names.

Individual samples are assumed to be files stored a two levels folder
structure such as the following:

    container_folder/
        category_1_folder/
            file_1.txt
            file_2.txt
            ...
            file_42.txt
        category_2_folder/
            file_43.txt
            file_44.txt
            ...

The folder names are used as supervised signal label names. The
individual file names are not important.
```

While the description says the file names are not important they are important for me, so the order of the elements of the bunchified objects should be kept synchronized.

And here is the EXAMPLE:

```
import string,os,shutil
from random import randint,choice

############## data preparation ##############################################
def id_generator(size, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
# utility, copies content of one directory into another with same structure
def merge_directories(root_src_dir,root_dst_dir):
    for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
        dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)
        if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
            os.mkdirs(dst_dir)
        for file_ in files:
            src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
            shutil.copy(src_file, dst_dir)
# create the directory structures with some random content       
d1='bunch_concatenation'
try:
    shutil.rmtree(d1)
except:
    pass
import itertools as itt
for d2,d3 in itt.product(('test_folder','train_folder')
                         ,('category_1_folder'
                          ,'category_2_folder'
                          # any number of categories really
                          )):
    directory=os.path.join(d1,d2,d3)
    os.makedirs(directory)
    for n_files in range(randint(2,5)):
        f=open(os.path.join(directory,id_generator(size=6))+'.txt',"w")
        f.writelines( "%s\n" %  
            "\n".join([str(id_generator(size=randint(5,8))) 
            for n_lines in range(randint(4,7))])
            )
        f.close()
test_folder=os.path.join(d1,'test_folder')    
train_folder=os.path.join(d1,'train_folder')
both_folder=os.path.join(d1,'both_folder') 
############ end data preparation ###########################################

# This is what I do in my actual code to get bunch_A and bunch_B:
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
bunch_A=load_files(test_folder)
bunch_B=load_files(train_folder)

# Now we have bunch_A and bunch_B which I need to concatenate into bunch_C

############ a workaround to serve as an example. ############################
# Create a both_folder that has all content from test_folder and train_folder.
shutil.copytree(test_folder, both_folder)
merge_directories(train_folder, both_folder)
# And load bunch_C from disk from both_folder
bunch_C=load_files(both_folder)
############# end workaround #################################################

print bunch_A
print bunch_B
print bunch_C    

#this is the function I want you to help me to write
def concatenate_bunches(bunch_A,bunch_B):
    """ What should go here?  
    How to create such bunch_C without actually copying the above directories 
    and loading the result from the disk?
    """
    return bunch_C 

# and this would be the usage example :-)
bunch_C=concatenate_bunches(bunch_A,bunch_B)


"""
Here is the directory structure again for your reference
please note that the actual filenames will be random strings

bunch_concatenation
    test_folder/
        category_1_folder/
            file_1.txt
            file_2.txt
            ...
            file_42.txt
        category_2_folder/
            file_43.txt
            file_44.txt
            ...
            file_99.txt
    train_folder/
        category_1_folder/
            file_111.txt
            file_112.txt
            ...
            file_142.txt
        category_2_folder/
            file_143.txt
            file_144.txt
            ...        
            file_150.txt
    both_folder/
        category_1_folder/
            file_1.txt
            file_2.txt
            ...
            file_42.txt
            file_111.txt
            ...
            file_142.txt
        category_2_folder/
            file_43.txt
            file_44.txt
            ...
            file_99.txt
            file_143.txt
            ...
            file_150.txt

"""
```

Printout of the bunches.

`Bunch_A
{'target_names': ['category_1_folder', 'category_2_folder'], 
'data': ['1ZGYOZA7\r\nPYSQLYSK\r\nJZZ7A3PL\r\nL16HB\r\nMA6IBJ\r\nREAZP9F\r\n', 'DXSCBE\r\nS7L4VD\r\nOWLPU7AV\r\n7VGH05R\r\n7QOZZH5\r\nT3DQZ\r\n', 'BS0T4IE\r\nXHQYZA\r\nCBJAH\r\n5WDJK\r\nW208C\r\nLYFFIU\r\n', 'HIAUSHF\r\n7IGHJL\r\nEDJBE\r\nF2SDY4\r\nWMO6RKO\r\nC6Y0G\r\n'], 
'target': array([1, 1, 0, 0]), 
'DESCR': None, 
'filenames': array([
       'bunch_concatenation\\test_folder\\category_2_folder\\KJO1WG.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\test_folder\\category_2_folder\\UI0203.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\test_folder\\category_1_folder\\FYFAEX.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\test_folder\\category_1_folder\\9AP5UJ.txt'], 
      dtype='|S60')}`

`Bunch_B 
{'target_names': ['category_1_folder', 'category_2_folder'], 
'data': ['T7QHJC\r\nFVTB5L\r\n3SB2PL9V\r\n4I7ZRL4\r\nAJ6M64RP\r\n', 'LVDJ5Q3\r\nT2GVTR\r\nIC8TAOLC\r\nH8LGY\r\nG3RVYGZM\r\nEYEHJO\r\nEC3B6WY\r\n', 'QKOTJO\r\nE3CI9VQ\r\nSJU9RV\r\nE1N57\r\n', '3LVXGJD\r\nFO6BBKC\r\nJIUXT17\r\n1USOO6\r\n71FQ1RR1\r\n', 'YI9CJMK\r\n98DSC9H4\r\nAUR1U4\r\n299LGBH\r\nXN5PIJ\r\n', '0DSW2E5M\r\nO4TPUZUL\r\nDQZYQ08\r\nHNE945\r\n', '275XS4VW\r\nPTDVG17W\r\nVELJHWFB\r\nTP62OLYE\r\nQ49OZG\r\n'], 
'target': array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), 
'DESCR': None, 
'filenames': array([
       'bunch_concatenation\\train_folder\\category_2_folder\\S05CO4.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\train_folder\\category_1_folder\\R0IYPO.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\train_folder\\category_1_folder\\FIS7PE.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\train_folder\\category_1_folder\\TRX13N.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\train_folder\\category_1_folder\\7V3ELC.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\train_folder\\category_2_folder\\FAL8AK.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\train_folder\\category_1_folder\\WDGLVH.txt'], 
      dtype='|S61')}`

`Bunch_C 
{'target_names': ['category_1_folder', 'category_2_folder'], 'data': ['LVDJ5Q3\r\nT2GVTR\r\nIC8TAOLC\r\nH8LGY\r\nG3RVYGZM\r\nEYEHJO\r\nEC3B6WY\r\n', 'T7QHJC\r\nFVTB5L\r\n3SB2PL9V\r\n4I7ZRL4\r\nAJ6M64RP\r\n', 'QKOTJO\r\nE3CI9VQ\r\nSJU9RV\r\nE1N57\r\n', 'DXSCBE\r\nS7L4VD\r\nOWLPU7AV\r\n7VGH05R\r\n7QOZZH5\r\nT3DQZ\r\n', '275XS4VW\r\nPTDVG17W\r\nVELJHWFB\r\nTP62OLYE\r\nQ49OZG\r\n', 'HIAUSHF\r\n7IGHJL\r\nEDJBE\r\nF2SDY4\r\nWMO6RKO\r\nC6Y0G\r\n', '0DSW2E5M\r\nO4TPUZUL\r\nDQZYQ08\r\nHNE945\r\n', '1ZGYOZA7\r\nPYSQLYSK\r\nJZZ7A3PL\r\nL16HB\r\nMA6IBJ\r\nREAZP9F\r\n', 'BS0T4IE\r\nXHQYZA\r\nCBJAH\r\n5WDJK\r\nW208C\r\nLYFFIU\r\n', 'YI9CJMK\r\n98DSC9H4\r\nAUR1U4\r\n299LGBH\r\nXN5PIJ\r\n', '3LVXGJD\r\nFO6BBKC\r\nJIUXT17\r\n1USOO6\r\n71FQ1RR1\r\n'],
 'target': array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]), 
'DESCR': None, 
'filenames': array([
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_1_folder\\R0IYPO.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_2_folder\\S05CO4.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_1_folder\\FIS7PE.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_2_folder\\UI0203.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_1_folder\\WDGLVH.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_1_folder\\9AP5UJ.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_2_folder\\FAL8AK.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_2_folder\\KJO1WG.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_1_folder\\FYFAEX.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_1_folder\\7V3ELC.txt',
       'bunch_concatenation\\both_folder\\category_1_folder\\TRX13N.txt'], 
      dtype='|S60')}`

I have just noticed that I have not implemented one thing - the filenames in the bunch_C have 'both_folder' in it but it has to be 'test_folder' or 'train_folder' accordingly to the source bunch. This came from the workaround. But this is actually not important for what I need to do with the resulting bunch.

Comment: Could you clarify precisely what you mean by "merge"? Suppose I want to perform `A + B` where `A` and `B` are both `Bunch` objects. What should happen if both have `data` entries that contain different lists? Should they be concatenated, or should only one of the lists from either `A` or `B` be used in the output? What about other types? What if `A["data"]` and `B["data"]` contain objects with disparate types?

Comment: I understand the point of having different structures and all the complexity coming with that. So here I am asking about **exactly same structure**. 

In my specific case I am loading two bunches from two directories and want to have another bunch that would look like if one of those two directories were copied into another. Same logic as when copying files (with overwriting) should apply. As a workaround I could just do the copy via OS and then load the resulting directory into the new bunch. 

So A and B should not contain objects with disparate types.

Comment: By "overwriting" I assume that you **don't** want any concatenation, i.e. where fields are duplicated, the one in `B` should always have precedence over `A`?

Comment: I guess you are right, this is a tough question. In my case the files have all unique names and the lists are created from their names and their content separately. So while overwriting the files would be OK, this actually won't happen if I were to merge directories. There would be pure concatenation in fact as they are mutually exclusive. Let me try to restate the requirement -  just concatenate everything, so the length(A.fieldX) +length(B.fieldX) = length((A+B).fieldX). Would that be straightforward?

Comment: length() being a pseudocode - just consider it being equal to len(). Let me take some time to prepare the example. Thanks for your attention to my question!

Comment: I see (you edited your previous comment after I replied). Depending on the contents of the fields there can be no guarantee that concatenation is even possible, especially for arrays that might have incompatible dimensions. Knowing the contents of the fields is also important because concatenation may require different methods depending on the types of objects involved. Could you edit your question to give a concrete example showing the exact behavior you are looking for, i.e. two example input Bunches and your desired output?

Comment: Sure, will do post the example code. Sorry for changing the comment, I did not see your comment as I did that. Just had not enough time to write it out properly, don't take this as a intentional. This would have been better discussed in a chat like the forum software suggests indeed.

Comment: No worries. The hard part in questions like this is often deciding exactly what sort of behavior you're actually looking for. I can't help you with that directly, but if you can come up with a clear example that illustrates it then I suspect it will be simple enough to implement. Take your time, think it through, and leave a comment when you've added an example to your question (I'd prefer not to chat right now).

Comment: I have added an example and rewritten my question to reflect the changed focus from merge to concatenate

Comment: That's not a very helpful example - it doesn't matter to me how you are generating your `Bunch` objects. What I want to see is two example bunches, say `A` and `B`, and a third bunch `C` which is the desired result of merging `A` with `B`. Something along the lines of `A = Bunch(foo='abc', bar=[1, 2, 3]); B = Bunch(foo='def', bar=[4, 5, 6]); C = Bunch(...)`.

Comment: The example script creates bunch_A, bunch_B and bunch_C. Have you checked their content? bunch_C is exactly what I expect as a result of concatenate_bunches(bunch_A,bunch_B)

Comment: I have added     `print bunch_A
    print bunch_B
    print bunch_C` so it prints out the actual content of the bunches